# Flutter button with gradient when pressed for it's highlight colour

Tags: button, flutter, dart, gradient

I have a button with a gradient colour so I want the gradient to reverse when it's pressed and then when the press is released for the gradient colour to go back to how it was when it started.

I have the gradient colours in an array so can be easily swapped but not sure how this can be done. I did this effect with React Native previously so am wondering how to do it with Flutter.

At the moment it's just using one colour with `highlightColor` when pressed but this looks too basic.

```
 const gradientcolours = [
  [Color(0xFF00000), Color(0xFFFFFFF)],
  [Color(0xFFFFFFF), Color(0xFF00000)]
];

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter, colors: gradientcolours[0]),
        ),
        child: RawMaterialButton(
          splashColor: Color(0xFF030303),
          highlightColor: Color(0xFF030303),
          child: Text('Press'),
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: onPressed,
          constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
          ),
          shape: CircleBorder(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
int index = 0;

/* ... */

Listener(
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
      gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter, colors: gradientcolours[index]),
    ),
    /* ... */
  ),
  onPointerDown: (_) {
    setState(() {
      index = 1;
    });
  },
  onPointerUp: (_) {
    setState(() {
      index = 0;
    });
  },
);
```

Comment: OMG you're a hero. I wasn't even aware of this `Listener` widget. It works perfectly.